# processing instruction is repeated twice

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<section level="sect1">
<title num="1.3"><content-style font-style="bold">Common Breaches</content-style></title>
<page num="9"/>
<section level="sect2">
<title><content-style font-style="bolditalic">Non-payment of Rent/Service Charge/Hiring Charge/Licence Fee</content-style></title>
<orderedlist type="manual">
<item num="1.3.1"><para>The most common breach in a Tenancy Agreement is the late payment or non payment of rent. The Tenancy Agreement usually provides for the right of the Landlord to re-enter the premises and determine the tenancy upon non-payment of rent for a period of time. This is in addition to the Landlord&apos;s rights to sue the Tenant for any outstanding rent and any monies owing under the tenancy up to the expiry of the tenancy and forfeit the security deposit.</para></item>
<item num="1.3.2"><para>The Landlord may commence what are known as Writ of Distress proceedings or Writ of Summons proceedings to claim for the unpaid rent. The Writ of Distress is the more effective remedy, however only rent may be recovered under the Writ of Distress.</para></item>
</orderedlist>
</section>
```

and i'm using the below XSLT.

```
<xsl:template name="section" match="section">
    <!-- Variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="classname">
        <!--Get name attribute of current node -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('section-',@level)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="size">
        <xsl:value-of select="string-length(ancestor::chapter[1]/@num)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="Chn">
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter[1]/@num"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="chapternumber">
        <!-- Get num attribute of parent node -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$size=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',$Chn)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Chn"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="sectnum">
        <xsl:number level="any" count="section" format="1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!--Create a string variable by concat string method  -->
    <xsl:variable name="sectionname">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('CH_',$chapternumber,'-SEC-', $sectnum)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Template Content  -->
    <xsl:if test="./page[1]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./page[1]"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <div class="{$classname}">
        <a name="{$sectionname}"> </a>
        <div class="section-title">
            <xsl:if test="not(contains(./@num,'unnumbered'))">
                <xsl:if test="./title/@num">
                    <span class="section-num">
                        <a name="{concat('P',translate(./title/@num,'.','-'))}"></a>
                        <xsl:value-of select="./title/@num"/>
                    </span>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="./title/child::node()[fn:not(self::page)]"/>
        </div>
        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>-->
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="para" match="section/para">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current()/@align">
            <div class="para align-{@align}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="current()/@num">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="child::node()[1][self::*]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="child::page[1]"/>
                    <div class="para">
                        <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <div class="para">
                        <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(([Cc]hapter)\s(\d+))">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number(regex-group(3)) &lt; number(9)">
                    <a href="{concat('er:#MCCL_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(3)),'00'),'/','MCCL_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(3)),'00'))}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[Pp]aragraphs\s([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\sand\s([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="number(regex-group(1)) &lt; number(9)">
                            <a
                                href="{concat('er:#MCCL_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'000'))}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' and')"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:text> and </xsl:text>
                            <a
                                href="{concat('er:#MCCL_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(3)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(3)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(4)),'000'))}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'and ')"/>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[Pp]aragraph\s([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="number(regex-group(1)) &lt; number(9)">
                                    <a
                                        href="{concat('er:#MCCL_CH_',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'00'),'/P',format-number(number(regex-group(1)),'0'),'-',format-number(number(regex-group(2)),'000'))}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                                    </a>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex="http://[^ ]+">
                                <xsl:matching-substring>
                                    <a href="{.}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </a>
                                </xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            </xsl:analyze-string>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="orderedlist">
    <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="orderitem" match="item">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(ends-with(@num, '.')) and fn:contains(@num,'.')">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <li class="item">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </li>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="item/para">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(../../@type,'manual')">
            <div class="para">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains(parent::item[1]/@num,'bull')">
                                <xsl:text>&#8226;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="not(ends-with(../@num, '.')) and fn:contains(../@num,'.')">
                                        <xsl:call-template name="phrase"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="../@num">
                                        <span class="item-num">
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::item[1]/@num"/>
                                        </span>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <span class="bullet-list">
                <xsl:value-of select="../../@type"/>
            </span>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="page">
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="pb">
        <xsl:text>label='</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/>
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>?</xsl:text>
    </xsl:processing-instruction>
  <a name="{concat('pg_',./@num)}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="phrase">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::title">
            <xsl:variable name="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',@num)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="newphrase" select="translate($phrase,'.','-')"/>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$newphrase">
                    </xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </a>
            <span class="phrase1">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',../@num)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="newphrase" select="translate($phrase,'.','-')"/>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$newphrase">
                    </xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </a>
            <span class="phrase">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@num"/>
            </span>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <!--<xsl:apply-templates/>-->


</xsl:template>
```

when i run this i'm getting output as below.

[image]
 here the processing instruction number 9 (`pb label='9'`) is getting duplicated, please let me know how can i get the below output.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you also include the template for phrase? I've run your code and I am not replicating your error. I see only one processing instruction in the output.

Comment: Hi @JoelM.Lamsen, I'm sorry for delayed reply, i've updated my answer wit phrase template. Thanks again

Comment: I'm struggling to replicate the error too. Have a look at http://xsltransform.net/eiQZDbt. Note that it might be worth reducing the XSLT to the barest minimum that replicates the problem (for example, you have a large template matching `text()` which could possible be removed for the purpose of just getting to the heart of the matter). Also, your XML is not quite well-formed, as it is missing a closing **section** tag. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TimC, now you can see the error [here](http://xsltransform.net/pPgCcoB), I've uncommented ` <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>` Thanka

Answer (score 0):

have your `page` template in a different mode

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="page[1]" mode="insert_page"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="page" mode="insert_page">
```